# How to switch to the new version of my website which is located in subdirectory of the old webste

Tags: .htaccess

I have a new version of my old website. Old website is still alive and it resides in the root of my hosting. I have upladed the new version to the subdirectory /new_website. It works fine when I use: www.mydomain.com/new_website
Now I want to to redirect www.mydomain.com to /new_website.
How to do this using .htaccess?